# Java exception when start hive on mac

Tags: macos, hive, config

I am new to hive and when i try to start hive after config, there's something wrong. I am totally lost. Anyone can help?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:344)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:671)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:615)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1485)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:64)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:74)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:2444)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:2456)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:338)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1483)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.hadoop.hive.shims.HadoopShims.getPassword(Lorg/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String;
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.getDataSourceProps(ObjectStore.java:324)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.ObjectStore.setConf(ObjectStore.java:219)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:76)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.<init>(RawStoreProxy.java:56)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RawStoreProxy.getProxy(RawStoreProxy.java:65)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.newRawStore(HiveMetaStore.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.getMS(HiveMetaStore.java:557)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.createDefaultDB(HiveMetaStore.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore$HMSHandler.init(HiveMetaStore.java:448)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.<init>(RetryingHMSHandler.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingHMSHandler.getProxy(RetryingHMSHandler.java:72)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStore.newRetryingHMSHandler(HiveMetaStore.java:5576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:193)
    ... 18 more
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your hadoop is in running condition or not.
Also check your hive-evn.sh and set JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME and hive path in hive-env.sh if not present.
Then from hive terminal execute hive. 
Also add the JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, HIVE_HOME in your .bashrc.

In case above is not working then :

By default hive uses derby database for storing meta tables.
Under metastore_db 2 lock files are created dbex.lck and db.lck. 
As a workaround just rename those 2 *.lck files and try to execute hive from the console again. See if it works or not.